# How to get retweet count for a certain tweet using tweepy or any other python method?

Tags: python, list, web-scraping, screen-scraping, tweepy

Is it possible to get retweet count for a certain tweet using tweepy python library? I want to get retweet count for every tweet which published from a particular twitter account. Is there are any python method with using tweepy for that? I have tried using beautifulsoup. But I am in the trouble with getting count for every tweet. It returns value only for the defined tweet ID. So how can I change this code to get values for each and every published tweet from that twitter account?

```
        id=[[tweet.id]for tweet in alltweets]


        html = requests.get("https://twitter.com/%s/status/%s" % ("usename", "userID"))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

        comments = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria'})[0].contents

    outtweets = [{'ID': tweet.id_str, 'Text': tweet.text, 'Date': tweet.created_at, 'author': tweet.user.screen_name,
                  'retweet-count': tweet.retweet_count, 'favourites-count': tweet.favorite_count, 'language': tweet.lang,
                  'reply-count': comments}for tweet in alltweets]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code can use for this problem.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for page in range(0, 50):
    url = "https://twitter.com/(user.screen.name)".format(page)
    html = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    tweets = soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class": "js-stream-item"})

for tweet in tweets:
    try:
        if tweet.find('p',{"class":'tweet-text'}):
            tweet_text = tweet.find('p', {"class": 'tweet-text'}).text.encode('utf8').strip()
            retweets = tweet.find('span', {"class": "ProfileTweet-action--retweet"}).text.strip()
            print(tweet_user, "|", retweets)
    except: AttributeError
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly set up your api and find the tweet ID that you want to count the retweets, then run the code below

```
retweets_list = api.retweets(ID)
print (retweets_list[0].retweet_count)
```